# Scale the person inside RGB image with IR

Tags: image, alignment, rgb, scaling, infrared

I have two facial images RGB and IR with dimensions of 500x500(both). I want to scale the person inside RGB to the scale of IR. I tried a lot of ways but failed. The motivation behind this is to align both images as one is a scaled version of the other.
[RGB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPN0H.jpg)
[Infrared image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIRzK.jpg)